# Spfx : Cannot read property 'consume' of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

[image]

Spfx Error :  Cannot read property 'consume' of undefined

**Sample Code wherte the error occured:**

```
public componentWillMount(): void {  
let serviceScope: ServiceScope = this.props.serviceScope;    
this.dataCenterServiceInstance = serviceScope.consume(UserProfileService.serviceKey);  

this.dataCenterServiceInstance.getUserProfileProperties().then((userProfileItems: IUserProfile) => {    
  for (let i: number = 0; i < userProfileItems.UserProfileProperties.length; i++) {  
    if (userProfileItems.UserProfileProperties[i].Key == "FirstName") {  
      userProfileItems.FirstName = userProfileItems.UserProfileProperties[i].Value;  
    }  
}
});

}
```

Comment: Try checking what you get in `this.props` and `this.props.serviceScope` by adding `console.log(this.props)` and `console.log(this.props.serviceScope)` at 1st line inside `componentWillMount()`. I think this issue is because you are getting `this.props.serviceScope` as undefined. Check how you are passing it to your props.

Comment: avoid using componentWillMount this is deprecated, use componentDidMount, once you update the state variable in it will re-render UI.